# elasticsearch cluster members are not turning into ready state in kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

i am a begginer in kubernetes i am trying to run an elasticsearch cluster in it for nthat i am following this (tutorial)[https://phoenixnap.com/kb/elasticsearch-helm-chart] followed all the commands as it is and in the ebnd when i do

```
kubectl get pods --namespace=default -l app=elasticsearch-master -w
```

i am getting

```
NAME                     READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
elasticsearch-master-0   0/1     Init:0/1   0          55s
elasticsearch-master-1   0/1     Init:0/1   0          55s
elasticsearch-master-2   0/1     Init:0/1   0          55s
```

they are not turning into ready state
and the command

```
helm test elasticsearch
```

got stuck and does not respond

here are the logs

```
kubectl logs -f elasticsearch-master-0
Error from server (BadRequest): container "elasticsearch" in pod "elasticsearch-master-0" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
 kubectl logs -f elasticsearch-master-1
Error from server (BadRequest): container "elasticsearch" in pod "elasticsearch-master-1" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
 kubectl logs -f elasticsearch-master-2
Error from server (BadRequest): container "elasticsearch" in pod "elasticsearch-master-2" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
```

and the `kubectl cluster-info`
returning

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"kube-dns:dns\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get resource \"services/proxy\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"kube-system\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "kube-dns:dns",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

that's all i know right now as i am a begenier in it please help why my elasticsearch nodes are not getting ready

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open issue around this helm on GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/issues/775).

```
Check once which storage class you have for PVC creation.
```

however, still, there could be multiple reasons for this issue like **PVC** is not getting created or others.

You can try if single node **Elasticsearch** working or not with **PVC** dynamic creation using :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app : elasticsearch
    component: elasticsearch
    release: elasticsearch
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app : elasticsearch
      component: elasticsearch
      release: elasticsearch
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app : elasticsearch
        component: elasticsearch
        release: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: cluster.name
          value: <SET THIS>
        - name: discovery.type
          value: single-node
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
        - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
          value: "false"
        image: elasticsearch:6.5.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: elasticsearch
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 150m
            memory: 512Mi
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          runAsUser: 1000
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: elasticsearch-data
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
        - chmod 777 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - chomod 777 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/node
        - chmod g+rwx /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - chgrp 1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        image: busybox:1.29.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: set-dir-owner
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: elasticsearch-data
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
  updateStrategy:
    type: OnDelete
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: elasticsearch-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```